# How to get text before the title?

Tags: 7

I suppose this is something about theming, but I haven't found a way to do this. I'm using the Pixtures Reloaded subtheme of Adaptive Themes.

I have a group of pages that need to have the structure:

     `Pretitle
     Title
     Subtitle
     Body`

that should come out looking like this:

`A true story:
               The Amazing Thing
              And Why it's Amazing
This is the story of...`

The title and subtitle are centered.

When I create a "Basic page", I have to specify a title for the page, and that title is displayed at the top-left of the page. I tried two ways to get something to be shown before the title.

First I defined a block called "Pretitle" and placed it in the theme's region called "Secondary content", which in the "Block region demonstration" is shown as being above the title. But when I displayed the page, the pretitle was exhibited under a big banner that said "Pretitle". That's not okay.

Next, I deleted that and defined a text field called "Pretitle" and placed that above the title in the Field Manager. When I displayed the page, the pretitle appeared at the very bottom of the page, under a line that said "Pretitle:". Again, not okay.

Aside from not seeing how to get a line of text to appear before the title (without a banner saying that it's a pretitle), I also have not a seen a way to get the title to be centered horizontally on the page.

I'm guessing this problem is because there's something really simple about composing pages in Drupal that I don't know about. Can you tell me what I'm missing?

Please don't give an answer that requires writing my own module because I'm not nearly ready to do that yet.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to center the title: find the appropriate css file, and change:

```
.title, #page-title
{
...
}
```

to include

```
.title, #page-title
{
  text-align:center;
}
```

It could be listed as either the class title, or id, depending on the theme. This is basic CSS.

to include the other fields:

1) you can alter the page.tpl.php file for theme, but if modules are out,  I assume most any php is out, so this is probably not suitable.

2) reassign your block if it otherwise worked, but in the block set up, change the Block Title to `<none>`

Comment: Thank you Geoff. In (2), deleting the contents of the block title worked. Re the first part, I didn't find ".title, #page-title", but I did find "h1#page-title {padding: 0; margin: 0 0 0.46em;}" in "sites\all\themes\pixture_reloaded\css\pixture_reloaded.css". I added "text-align:center;" there, but that didn't have any effect that I saw. However, looking around in that CSS file, I found something on Extensions, so I went back to the theme settings and found "Extensions > Title Styles", which allowed me to set the title alignment. So I got both parts of the problem solved. Thank you.

Comment: ok - you could have added the css to the end of file since it wasn't already there. An easy way to find it is to use Developer tools in either Firefox or Chrome - it would allow you to narrow down what css needs to change, and on what line in what file it is being assigned